# passing attributes in the tinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, tinymce

I'm trying to implement jquery mobile tables with in the TinyMCE editor. I passed the jquery mobile css and js files to the iframe head.In my html file I have specified data-role="page and given the table attributes as well. and in extended valid element section I have specified the data attributes as well eg - [data-role|data-mode] . how ever it seems these attribute are not been recognize by the jquery mobile in my iframe head . none of the classes are there which needs to be there to the table or page is there .

any ideas Im open .

Comment: Are you trying to change the HTML within the iframe? If so then this is not possible. It would be a massive security risk if people could amend pages they are iframing in.

Comment: as a matter of fact I was. How to pass the attribute otherwise ?

Comment: @JanR: this should work if both (window and iframe have the same document.domain)

Comment: @Thariama, fair enough I would have expected the iframe to be in a different domain entirely why would you iframe from the same domain...

Comment: because tinymce uses an iframe to let the user edit content. i assumed you were talking about the editor iframe